# SQL delete unnecessary characters from a row and parse a table into a new table

Tags: mysql, sql, string, case, sql-null

I have created the below code:

```
with t as (select *,
    case 
    when `2kids`= '1' then '2kids' else'' end as new_2kids,
    case 
    when `3kids`= '1' then '3kids' else'' end as new_3kids,
    case
    when kids= '1' then 'kids' else'' end as kids
    from test.family)
select concat_ws('/',new_2kids, new_3kids, new_kids) as 'nc_kids'
from t;
```

If I run this query my output will be:

**nc_kids**

```
2kids/new_3kids/ 
2kids// 
/new_3kids/new_kids 
2kids/new_3kids/new_kids
```

How can I remove all the unnecessary '/' which not followed by character.
For example:

**nc_kids**

```
2kids/new_3kids 
2kids
new_3kids/new_kids 
2kids/new_3kids/new_kids
```

Comment: Use TRIM() function.

Comment: @Akina actually it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat_ws()` ignore `null`s, so you can just turn the empty strings to `null` values at concatenation time:

```
select concat_ws('/', 
    nullif(new_2kids, ''), 
    nullif(new_3kids, ''), 
    nullif(new_kids,  '')
) as nc_kids
from t;
```

Better yet, fix the `case` expressions so they produce `null` values instead of empty stings in the first place:

```
with t as (
    select f.*,
        case when `2kids`= 1 then '2kids' end as new_2kids,
        case when `3kids`= 1 then '3kids' end as new_3kids,
        case when kids   = 1 then 'kids'  end as kids
    from test.family f
)
select concat_ws('/',new_2kids, new_3kids, new_kids) as nc_kids
from t;
```

Comment: Actually it shows only NULL or    new_2kids/new_3kids/new_kids.

Comment: @Thkas: are you sure that you are running MySQL (which you tagged)? What is returned when you run `select version()`?

Comment: I run on impala sql queries